# Requirejs Gruntfile cannot locate almond

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, almond

i'm trying to use almond.js in grunt to combine my files into on .js and uglify it.
My configuration in grunt is like this:

```
requirejs: {
                compile: {
                    options: {
                        baseURL: "www/js/lib",
                        mainConfigFile: 'www/js/main.js',
                        name: '../../../node_modules/almond/almond',
                        include: '../main',
                        out:'../target/app.min.js',
                        findNestedDependencies: true,
                        optimize: 'uglify',
                    }
                }
            },
```

my main.js is this:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js/lib",

    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        tpl: '../tpl'
    },

    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone-indexeddb': {
            deps: ['backbone', 'IndexedDBShim']
        },
        'IndexedDBShim': {
            deps: ['backbone']
        }
    }
});
```

If i try to run grunt requirejs i get an error: 
Error: Error: ERROR: module path does not exist: project/www/js/js/lib/../../../node_modules/almond/almond.js for module named: ../../../node_modules/almond/almond. Path is relative to: project
    at /project/node_modules/grunt-contrib-requirejs/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:25964:35

which i do not understand, where does the second /js/ in the path come from? It does not exist in my file structure, i have my project folder set up like this

```
project
  gruntfile
  node_modules
     almond
        almond.js
  www
    index.html
    js
        app
        lib
        main.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, i'm configuring the baseurl twice, shouldn't do that. If i remove the baseurl parameter in the gruntfile it works fine.